# How do I programmatically split a multi-page tiff into single pages using Adobe Acrobat and it's exposed COM Objects?

Tags: python, com, split, adobe, acrobat

I want to programmatically (using Python) split a multi-page tiff into single pages using Adobe Acrobat's exposed COM Objects.

I am writing this in order to answer my own question in order to put a viable answer out there, as I did not find anyone doing this on SO or any other forum.

Please, let me know what you think about my solution and feel free to leave your way of doing this.

Comment: Will you post the code you've written so far? What exactly is the problem you're facing? What output are you receiving? How is it different than you expect?

Comment: great story, needs more questions and code though.

Comment: I am actually writing this so I can answer my own question (as I did not find the answer to this question on here yet). I am a new user, however, so they won't let me answer my own question without waiting 8 hours after posting.

Comment: Please don't leave me bad rep I'm trying to answer a question that doesn't seem to have been asked yet. I will leave my solution as an answer when SO lets me but I am very interested in other's solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

def acrobat_split(f_path,f_name,f_ext):


    # Connect to Adobe Acrobat.
    avDoc = Dispatch("AcroExch.AVDoc")

    # Open the input file (as a pdf).
    src = f_path+'\\'+f_name+f_ext
    avDoc.Open(src,src)


    pdDoc = avDoc.GetPDDoc()
    page_ct = pdDoc.GetNumPages()

    # Set dst.
    dst = f_path+'\\'+f_name+PAGE_DIV+".tif"

    jsObject = pdDoc.getJSObject()

    #Here you can save as many other types by using, for instance: "com.adobe.acrobat.xml"
    jsObject.saveAs(dst,"com.adobe.acrobat.tiff")

    pdDoc.Close()
    del pdDoc
```